# Where and how to download prism 5 libraries

Tags: mvvm, prism, wpf-4.0, prism-4

Hi I tried downloading the prism 5 libraries(dlls) by following these steps here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405471(v=pandp.40).aspx

Unfortunately I donot know where to download the libraries like prism.mvvm, pubsubevent and rest. according to the given link if I try to compile other quick starts I run into 407 authentication exception and somebody suggested ([here](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/546820)) to manually add assemblies but I donot have assemblies to download.

Please suggest ASAP

Comment: How come someone down voted this... did you know the problem.. damn. See the links man there is a problem this is not joke

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install nuget and add the reference via nuget. its much easier to manage the libraries.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism

Otherwise download from below location,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42537

Sabaresh

Comment: the other location I tried but it does not give me libraries it gives me only source code. And when I compiled I get some 407 exception as I mentioned earlier. Can you elobarate on other location

Comment: and if you CAN'T install nuget?